# Can I alias variables without incurring the storage cost of a reference?

Tags: c++, alias

If I have the following code:

```
struct someStruct
{
  int x;
  int y;
}

class someClass
{
  public:
    someStruct m_member;

    alias      m_x = m_member.x; // I am aware alias is not a keyword and even if it was, I cannot assign it a value like this
    alias      m_y = m_member.y; // I am aware alias is not a keyword and even if it was, I cannot assign it a value like this
}
```

Can I give aliases to `m_member.x` and `m_member.y` without incurring the extra storage cost of a reference (which is the same as a pointer)? Something similar to a typedef?

Comment: Nod. Such an 'alias' keyword would certainly be valuable when you want to deprecate an old name without breaking existing code or to transparently compose one data structure of another. D pleasantly has the "alias" keyword, and C++ has "using", but it sadly only works for type names rather than field names. I hope C++ someday adopt D's ability (but it would likely be via the "using" keyword instead of "alias").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write inline access functions:

```
class someClass
{
public:
  someStruct m_member;
  int& mx() { return m_member.x; }
  int& my() { return m_member.y; }
  int const& mx() const { return m_member.x; }
  int const& my() const { return m_member.y; }
};
```

Then you can access the members as follows:

```
someClass foo;
foo.mx() = 3;
foo.my() = 2*foo.mx();
```

It's not *exactly* the same syntax, but close, and a reasonably good compiler will completely optimize away the inline functions.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Thanks for pointing out that omission; I've now added them.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario I would just use a reference as it's what they're suited for.  If a reference overhead is really too much I would just forgo the alias and use the full expression.

However you could achieve this with a macro (read: **evil**)

```
class someClass
{
  public:
    someStruct m_member;
#define m_x m_member.x
#define m_y m_member.y

  ...

#undef m_x
#undef m_y
};
```

I would highly recommend **not** doing this though.  Like all macros though it has some unintended consequences (could cause incorrect referencing for other valid uses of `m_x` within the type).

For example

```
struct s1 {
  int m_x;
};

class someClass {
public:
  someStruct m_member;
#define m_x m_member.x
#define m_y m_member.y

  ...
  void Example(S1& s1) { 
    s1.m_x = 42;  // This wouldn't compile and you'd get terrible error messages
  }
};
```

Comment: Note that if you `#undef` the macros within the class, clients can't use them. But if you don't `#undef` them, the result is probably worse.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I was trying to limit my *hack / macro* to the smallest possible area :)

Comment: I think if you're going to overload `m_x` like that, you're looking to get bitten in any case.

Comment: It's called a "hackro" for a reason.